# Python to read Excel cell with the value calculated by the formulas but not the formula strings themselves

Tags: excel, python-2.7

I am using Python openpyxl package to read values from Excel cells. Cells with formulas always return formula strings instead of the calculated values. I'd rather avoid using 'data_only=True' when loading the workbook as it wipes out all the formulas and I do need to retain some of them. Seemingly a problem not so difficult but turns out to be quite challenging. Appreciate it very much if anyone can shed some lights on this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you looked into Pandas [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) capabilities?

Comment: This may sound a bit crazy but reading the file twice (one with `data_only=True` and the other with `data_only=False`) and mapping the two datasets may be a solution for this.

Comment: Thank you both very much. Metropolis: Tried Pandas - same issue. It picked up cell value with formulas as NaN. Abdou: Interesting...never thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out myself and like to share with you guys. xlwings actually does the job while openpyxl/xlrd seem to have failed around this issue.

Comment: To make your answer more complete, I suggest you add an example on how this works. Can xlwings be used as the engine in `pd.read_excel()`?

Comment: xlwings works perfectly in this situation. But only drawback is xlwings is not available for Linux.